# Findstr /g with token or delim

Tags: string, batch-file, token, delimiter, findstr

Suppose we have 2 files

First.txt

```
123
456
```

And Second.txt

```
789;123
123;def
482;xaq
```

What i need is to find the lines in the second file only containing entries of the first file in first column (token 1, delim ; ).
This is what i need:

Output.txt

```
123;def
```

Of course,

```
findstr /g:first.txt second.txt
```

will output both lines:

```
789;123
123;def
```

Any idea how i can mix findstr and for /f to get the needed output?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the elements in the first column are of the same length, then the simple answer would be

```
findstr /b /g:first.txt second.txt
```

Note however that if `first.txt` contains a line `12` then this would match `123;abc` **and** `129;pqr` in the second file.

Comment: Hmm great finding. Your solution seems to work for any length actually. Just what i need

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the super-limited regex capabilities of `findstr` and compare each line of first.txt to only the very beginning of each line of second.txt.

```
@echo off
for /F %%A in (first.txt) do findstr /R /C:"^%%A;" second.txt
```

The `/R` flag means that the search string should be treated as a regular expression. The `^` in the search string means that `%%A` comes at the very beginning of the line. The `;` is a literal semicolon that will prevent the `123` line from picking up `1234;abcd` in second.txt.

Comment: edited it as ^%%A.; to suit my needs. Seems to work as expected. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Without executing a separate `findstr` for each value and to avoid the problem with partial matches at the start of the line, you can try with

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    ( cmd /q /c"(for /f "delims=" %%a in (first.txt) do echo(%%a;)" 
    ) | findstr /g:/ /l /b second.txt
```

What it does is read `first.txt` and echo each line with the delimiter. This output is retrieved by the `findstr` using `/g:/` to use the standard input as the source for the elements to match, that will be considered as literals (`/l`) at the start of the line (`/b`) in the `second.txt` file

Comment: Very nice. I think this is the first time I have ever seen `/` used with the `/G` option!

Comment: seems to be working. However, work for exact length in both files

Answer (score 0):

Is the general form for CSV. Note in batch %A becomes %%A.

```
for /f "delims=," %A in (csv.txt) do findstr /c:"%A" file2.txt
```

Here's the output

```
C:\Users\User>for /f "delims=," %A in (csv.txt) do findstr /c:"%A" csv1.txt

C:\Users\User>findstr /c:"55" csv1.txt
55,61,hi there, Good

C:\Users\User>findstr /c:"60" csv1.txt
54,60,hi there, Bad

C:\Users\User>findstr /c:"Bad" csv1.txt
54,63,hi there, Bad
54,60,hi there, Bad

C:\Users\User>findstr /c:"55" csv1.txt
55,61,hi there, Good
```

Contents of two files.

```
55,60
60,60
Bad,60
55,60
```

and

```
55,61,hi there, Good
54,62,hi there, Good
54,63,hi there, Bad
54,60,hi there, Bad
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I tried your command but i get the same output `789;123`
`123;def` . Thank you!

Comment: These aren't CSV files, though; they're just in a similar format. This guy has semicolon-delimited values, so it should be `delims=;` instead.

Comment: It's an example for you to change to suit.